# Spring roo - including jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-roo

I have added jQuery link to load-scripts.tagx as following.

```
<script src="custom/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It compiles fine and page loads fine, when i check the generated source it is as following 
in the generated html, which is perfectly fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="custom/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"/>
```

This loads the js as expected, but my only concerned is that it is trying to load jquery-1.10.2.min.map and this fails since there is no such file. I want to figure-out why this is happening.

Comment: With further search on google found out that minified version has a link to above mentioned map file which links to original file. Currently use of this feature is supported in Dev tools of WebKit nightly builds, Google Chrome, or Firefox 23+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this map file in your project

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.map

Answer (score 1):

Latest gvNIX 1.2.1 includes an addon to move your project to jQuery. Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/gvnix/wiki/QuickStartGvnix